# AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect in SongsController#index "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

I follow the tutorial from this website: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails--net-18437#disqus_thread to create a simple music streaming app.

But I get error "Uninitialized constant SongsController::BUCKET" while runing the rails server. Can anyone explain why I get this error and how to solve it, thank you? I use rails 4.0.5

I created a new rails project, I only use the following files, Here are my code:

Gemfile ( I add this line )

```
gem 'aws-s3', '~> 0.6.3'
```

application.rb (all codes )

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AudioDemo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => 'my acess key',
      :secret_access_key => 'my secret key'
    )
    ENV['BUCKET']='my bucket name'
  end
end
```

songs_controller.rb ( all codes )

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @songs = AWS::S3::Bucket.find(ENV['BUCKET']).objects
  end

  def upload
    begin
        AWS::S3::S3Object.store(sanitize_filename(params[:mp3file].original_filename), 
          params[:mp3file].read, ENV['BUCKET'], :access => :public_read)
        redirect_to root_path
    rescue
        render :text => "Couldn't complete the upload"
    end
  end

  def delete
    if (params[:song])
        AWS::S3::S3Object.find(params[:song], ENV['BUCKET']).delete
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :text => "No song was found to delete!"
    end
  end

  private

    def sanitize_filename(file_name)
        just_filename = File.basename(file_name)
        just_filename.sub(/[^\w\.\-]/,'_')
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
root :to => "songs#index"
  get "upload" => "songs#upload", :as => "upload"
  get "delete" => "songs#delete", :as => "delete"
```

index.html.rb

```
 <ul>
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
   <li><%= song.key %> - <%= link_to "Delete",  "songs/delete/?song=" + song.key, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + song.key + '?' %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>

<h2>Upload a new MP3:</h2>
<%= form_tag upload_path, :method => "post", :multipart => true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag "mp3file" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after making that change in your application.rb file?

Comment: What do you have at the top of songs_controller.rb?  What do you require/extend there?

Comment: yes, I restart the server several times, and at the top of songs_controller.rb is nothing.

Comment: So, this is not something the server restart will sort. Its the scoping problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can do something like that:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => 'my access key',
      :secret_access_key => 'my secret key'
)
ENV['BUCKET']='mybucket'
```

So, now you can replace BUCKET with ENV['BUCKET'] in your controller.

Comment: But it still doesn't work, I followed your guide and get this new error: 
"AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect in SongsController#index"

"The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint."

Comment: Oh dear you asked the problem because you couldn't enter to specific variable BUCKET. I just solve that. Now this is the problem is something you might not configure properly or eighter you didn't replace BUCKET in all the places. please do a check.

Comment: I've just updated the code, I think I already replace BUCKET in all the places. If the problem is the configuration,what should I do?

Comment: Give me more details I will help you solving that. no worries.

Comment: Thank you, I've just updated the question, all in detail

Comment: AH, I don't know why, but now it starts working, anyway thank you very much for your help :)